# Me carga los botones fuera del formulario en blade laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

Tengo una tabla y la recorro con `@foreach` por cada registro genero un modal de confirmacion para eliminar el usuario, en este modal tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="{{URL::action('UserController@destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Si, eliminar</button>
 </form>
```

Cuando doy clic al botón no manda el submit y si miro el html en el navegador veo que el boton lo genera fuera del formulario:

```
    <form action="http://localhost:8000/usuarios/14" method="post"></form> 
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"> 
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="P6E1IJqljnKoOKhmVnQiTSKBEIyqfXIe5yI7tWIg"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Si, eliminar </button>
```

ya borre la cache con `php artisan cache:clear` y nada, ayuda!!

Comment: ¿Estás usando tablas y los elementos de formulario están en dos o más celdas?

Comment: si es en laravel con Tailwind solo usa la class="inline-flex" y listo no se bajara

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con helpers de blade (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers).
Aunque lo mejor seria realizarlo atreves de ajax.

```
<form action="{{URL::action('UserController@destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Si, eliminar</button>
</form>
```